# How to use many variables in assembly

Tags: variables, assembly, x86-16

In c or c++ or other mid or high level language we can use as many variables as possible. What about assembly?

Suppose i did this code.

```html
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    lf equ 0ah
    cr equ 0dh


    crlf db cr,lf,'$'    
.code
main proc
              
    ;initialize database          
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov bx,01    
    
    fop:
    mov cx, bx
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,'*'
    
    
    top:
        int 21h
        loop top
        
    inc bx
    
    lea dx, crlf
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h   
    
    
    cmp bl, 05
    jg _end_this    
    loop fop
    
    _end_this:     

main endp    
end main
```

The result is...

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Now I want to do something like below.

```html
.
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

I am trying to do that by using another variable to create a loop for the spaces. With decreasing spaces such a pattern would be possible. But all the main registers seems booked. ax,bx,cx,dx. What to do now. What if I needed more variables.

Comment: _"But all the main registers seems booked. ax,bx,cx,dx"_. `cx` is only used within the `top` loop, so adding another loop that also uses `cx` won't be a problem. By the way, `jg _end_this` / `loop fop` can be replaced by `jle fop`.

Comment: Suppose there was another register i could use.. say ex

 mov bx,01    
 mov ex,04
    
    fop:
    mov cx,ex
    mov ah,2
    mov dl, ' ' ; space

    gop:
        int 21h
    end gop

    mov cx, bx
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,'*'
    
    
    top:
        int 21h
        loop top
        
    inc bx
    dec ex

Comment: You don't need any additional registers. You can just use `cx` as I said in my previous comment. The fact that you're using a register _somewhere_ in your program doesn't mean that that register is used _everywhere_ in the program.

Comment: but how can I use cx to initialize cx for loop

mov cx, cx

Comment: And also what if I needed more ,like 10 variables (not this program)

Comment: The number of spaces you want to print is 5 - `bx`, so that's simple to calculate. If you really _had_ run out of registers you would've had to spill one or more of them to memory temporarily. Either to the stack with `push/pop` or to some variable declared in the `.data` section.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be NOT to use spaces but to use screen coordinates. The asterisks you want to display are going down (Y coordinate increases) while the beginning of every line moves to the left (X coordinate decreases). Next program applies this concept. It was made with EMU8086 and it is full of comments to help you understand. Just copy, paste and run :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

    x   db 5 ;X COORDINATE ON SCREEN.
    y   db 1 ;Y COORDINATE ON SCREEN. 
    ast db '*$'
    len dw 1 ;LENGTH OF EVERY ASTERISKS LINE.

.code           
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax       

display_lines:

;GOTOXY.    
    mov dl, x
    mov dh, y
    mov ah, 2 ;SERVICE TO SET CURSOR POSITION.
    mov bh, 0 ;PAGE.
    int 10h   ;BIOS SCREEN SERVICES.  

    mov cx, len ;HOW MANY ASTERISKS TO DISPLAY.
display_asterisks:         

;DISPLAY ONE ASTERISK.    
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset ast
    int 21h    

    loop display_asterisks

;PREPARE FOR NEXT LINE.    
    inc len ;NEXT LINE HAS ONE MORE ASTERISK.
    inc y   ;NEXT LINE GOES DOWN.
    dec x   ;NEXT LINE MOVES TO THE LEFT.
    jnz display_lines ;IF X != 0 : REPEAT.

;FINISH PROGRAM.
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
```

With screen coordinates we no longer need line breaks.

Let me know if it worked for you.